# dropdown menubar alignment issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, navbar

I have created a drop-down mega menu, Its width is 960px, and its dropdown div box width is 900px, but i need is when i hover the mouse on last or second last menu, the dropdown div comes with 900px and a big scroll bar occur on the page, i need it auto adjust to float right or proper alignment,

Working Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/XygGQ/

```
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Music</a><!-- Begin 4 columns Item -->
        <div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->

<li><a href="#" class="drop">Acting</a>
 <div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
 </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->

<li><a href="#" class="drop">Singing</a>
<div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>        
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->

<li><a href="#" class="drop">Sports</a>
        <div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->
<li><a href="#" class="drop">Fitness</a>
        <div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->
<li><a href="#" class="drop">MMA</a>
<div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->
<li><a href="#" class="drop">Modelling</a>
<div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->
<li><a href="#" class="drop">Dance</a>
<div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->
<li><a href="#" class="drop">Creative Arts & Design</a>
<div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->

<li><a href="#" class="drop">Kids Talent</a>
<div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->

<li><a href="#" class="drop">Others</a>
<div class="dropdown_5columns"><!-- Begin 4 columns container -->
            <div class="col_5">
                <ul>
 <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div><!-- End 4 columns container -->
    </li><!-- End 4 columns Item -->

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `position: relative;` from #menu li to just #menu. Then the dropdown will position itself from the menu instead of the menu-link.

Comment: No problems, i would also recommend to use display: none; and display: block; to hide the dropdowns instead of left: -999em.

Answer (score 1):

in `#menu li {}`

remove this line `position:relative;`